# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when, $y \arcsin x - x \arctan y = 1$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Yesterday was my class test and I found this question.

Find $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$ when, $\displaystyle y \arcsin x - x \arctan y = 1$

I have read the question for arctanx as $1/1 + x^2$. But that is applied only, when the question is

Find difference is along x (dy/dx) and the function has the x as the variable.

How would I solve the above equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we have , $$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\arcsin x+y\cdot\frac{d(\arcsin x)}{dx}-\frac{dx}{dx}\cdot \arctan y -x\cdot\frac{d(\arctan y)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(1)}{dx}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\arcsin x+y\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\arctan y -x\cdot\frac1{1+y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Now group the terms containing $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: I can sense a product rule in it! :) Simple and easy, but can you please elaborate how can I use `d(arctany)/dy` while I need to be using `d/dx`? I mean how was chain rule applied which values changed to variables?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan, $$\frac{d f(y)}{dx}=\frac{ d f(y)}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(y)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: Oh haha :D that was simple! Thanks alot sir g :) will accept it as answer in one minute! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the total differentiation of an implicit function $F =\operatorname F(x,y) = 0$. You end with
$\displaystyle \frac {\operatorname dy}{\operatorname dx} = - \dfrac{ \frac {\operatorname dF}{\operatorname dx} }{ \frac { \operatorname dF }{\operatorname dy}}$
and you wil arrive to what lab bhattarcharjee gives.

Comment: nice one! :) thanks for info..:)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan. Glad to have helped

Comment: @Arjang. Thanks for editing. Since I am almost blind, everything beside ASCII is difficult to me.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : it is my pleasure